# unable to execute sudo -S

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

**Problem:**
unable to execute a script

**Given:**
permissions have been changed to 777

the password has been inserted with \n

bash 4.3 version

**script:**

```
<shebang>
sudo -S < /home/x/Documents/somePassword
/opt/lamp/lamp start
```

**output:**

```
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user] [command]
usage: must be a root
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean

```
sudo -S /opt/lamp/lamp start < /home/x/Documents/somePassword
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't enter most passwords this way
You can change /etc/sudoers to run some commands without password

username ALL = NOPASSWD: /opt/lamp/lamp